# Refactor repetitive view HTML into each loop for Ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, foreach

I have the following HTML code

```
<div class="col-xs-1"> 
    <img src="/assets/X.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="X">
    <h6>X</h6>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-1">
    <img src="/assets/Y.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Y">
    <h6>Y</h6>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-1"> 
    <img src="/assets/Z.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Z">
    <h6>Z</h6>
</div>
...
```

As you can see there's a ton of redundancy (especially since it's actually repeating 10+ times not just the 3 I have here). I'm trying to think through how to make something like this into a DRY each loop, but am having a bit of difficulty.

I initially thought to just declare in the controller for this view:

```
@images = ["X", "Y", "Z"]
```

And then in the view do

```
<% @images.each do |image| %>
<div class="col-xs-1">
    <img src="/assets/#{image}.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="#{image}">
    <h6>"#{image}"</h6>
</div>
<% end %>
```

But this syntax must not be right since all of the images show up broken. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Also, if this turned out to be a not very efficient way of refactoring, I'm very open to suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're expecting the `#{image}` to interpolate, but that code in image `src`, `alt` attributes are just text and not ruby.  Same applies for text in `h6` tag.

You need to use erb scriplets `<%=...%>` around them to output their values.

Update your view code with the following:

```
<% @images.each do |image| %>
<div class="col-xs-1">
    <img src="<%= "/assets/#{image}.jpg" %>" class="img-responsive" alt="<%= "#{image}" %>">
    <h6><%= "#{image}" %></h6>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: quick follow up question, I'm extrapolating rules of interpolation from your answer and from what I know... now let's say that I want th image to link to a pre-specified path. For example, if the image were called The Blue Sky, the path should be photographer_the_blue_sky_path. Therefore I'm writing `<a href="<%= photographer_"#{image.str.downcase.tr(" ","_")}"_path %>" class="thumbnail">` but this does generates an `expecting ')'` error. Can you easily see what's wrong?

Comment: Try: `<a href="<%= "photographer_#{image.str.downcase.tr(' ','_')}_path" %>" class="thumbnail">`.  Just to clear the confusion, interpolation works for any ruby expression within `#{}` which is wrapped by double quotes.

Comment: Oh I see what's going on in... you have to put the double quotes around the entire photographer...path, rather than just the part that needs interpolation. That makes a lot of sense thanks. Do you know why though, now I'm getting an error that says `undefined method `str' for "Natural Environments":String`, yet by virtue of that last part of the error, the variable is indeed a string...

Comment: @james, `image` is already a string isn't it?  Why did you do `image.str`?  or did you mean `image.to_s`?

Comment: oh man of course! ARG thank you so much! (i just copied and pasted str.downcase.tr and completely forgot to delete the str)

Comment: if you're  not absolutely sick of me yet, I have one more point of confusion. I just tested it, and if the code is written explicitly as `photographer_the_blue_sky_path`, I can see that the URL it goes to is photographer/the_blue_sky, and clicking it works. Now though, with the ruby interpolation, the URL that it goes to is /photographer_the_blue_sky_path, which doesn't work because there is no such route. I suspect that what's happening is that before, the code was recognized as a path, whereas now it's recognizes as a string, thoughts?

Comment: @james, no worries.  I feel horrible that I didn't catch this before.  I can't try this right now but can you try `<%= asset_path "blue_sky.jpg" %>` and check the output.  Replace image with your desired image.

Comment: oh that's great! you gave me just enough insight to tweak it myself. since my path is photographer/the_blue_sky, what worked for me was `<%= asset_path "photographer/#{image.downcase.tr(' ',"_')}"` thanks so much!